Python metaprogramming, dynamic types, and static type checking
update
I think my issue is that I am looking for something akin to typescript mappings, like
type newT<X> = { [keyof X]: <some other type> }
And based on my research, python does not offer this kind of advanced type inference / manipulation.
The implementation below works (correct functionality), but it does not seem like I will be able to produce the advanced type signatures that I want. FWIW even the most recent version of the book Fluent Python, in its metaprogramming section, seems not to implement any sort of type checking.
goal
I am playing around with a dataframe framework - I want to be able to flexibly interact with (pandas) dataframes either in  python or in sql, without having to cast them to dicts, etc.
For example, let's say we have a df, whose rows look like this kind of dataclass:
@dataclass
class Record:
    name: str
    phone: str
    email: str

(I mean that we have 3 columns, 'name', 'phone', 'email', and each row has three strs, one for each)
The goal is to have contacts = make_dataframe_dict(df, Record), which will then support queries like this
contacts.name['Harry']  # (internally) returns the row with row.name == "Harry"

Importantly,

For contacts, attributes name, phone, email should be recognized by the type checker (i.e. contacts.name autocompletes)
the expected typing of 'Harry' should be expected to match the type on Record.name (str). (we're assuming uniques for 'Harry' for now)

Moreover
We want contacts.name['Harry'] to be treated by the typechecker as type Record, so that we can do
contacts.name['Harry'].phone # return type str, and with autocompletion of .phone, .email, .name

Also
contacts.list() # returns a list or iterator of List[T] where T is the dataclass type
current approach
The code below does work and it has most of the type inference that I want. We tell the system that the return value of our factory function conforms to both T (dataclass type) and DataClassDict. It accomplishes all of the requirements above except

contacts.name is inferred to be of type str and so we get no checking of the get value, 'Harry' (i.e., contacts.name['Harry'] does not make sense) and contats.name['Harry'].phone certainly does not make sense. This happens because contacts.name is present on contacts since contacts "conforms to" T, so contacts.name is typed according to the dataclass, T
it is fragile because none of the methods on dataclass are implemented; we "implement" only the attributes

T = TypeVar('T')


def make_dataframe_dict(df: DataFrame, dclass_type: Type[T]) -> Union[T, DataFrameDict[T]]:
    return DataFrameDict(df, dclass_type)


# This is like a partial so that `contacts.name` can return an object which can in turn 
# implement `__getitem__`
class DataFrameView(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame, dataclass_type: Type[T], column: str):
        self.df = df
        self.dataclass_type = dataclass_type
        self.column = column

    def __getitem__(self, key) -> T:
        if key in self.df[self.column].values:
            row = self.df[self.df[self.column] == key].iloc[0]
            return self.dataclass_type(*row)
        else:
            raise KeyError(f"Key '{key}' not found in DataFrame column '{self.column}'")


class DataFrameDict(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, df: DataFrame, dataclass_type: Type[T]):
        self.df = df
        self.dataclass_type = dataclass_type
        self._validate_dataclass() # validates that fields and columns match


    def __getattr__(self, attr) -> DataFrameView[T]:
        if attr in self.df.columns:
            # returns a sort of partial that can then implement __getitem__
            return DataFrameView(self.df, self.dataclass_type, attr)
        else:
            raise AttributeError(f"'DataFrame' object has no attribute '{attr}'")

    def list(self) -> List[T]:
        return [self.dataclass_type(*row) for row in self.df.itertuples(index=False)]


What I really want to do (but have been unable to make work) is to have some sort of metaclass (I think).
@classDecorator # or metaclass
class RecordDF:
    name: str
    phone: str
    email: str

We call RecordDF(df: Dataframe) and the __new__ method basically needs to create the types that we need. Admittedly I don't know if this would work with static type checking.
So I actually might need to "compile" separate types from the class RecordDF definition? I don't know if this is possible or how to do it.
But what I do know is that the problem is well-specified, and I should need to define these types only once, and I do know that metaprogramming solves these sorts of problems.
It would be even cooler if type inference could be done entirely dynamically on the dataframe so that we do not even need to define the fields; we would write code to infer types and names from the df itself.

why, oh why, would you not use Python comments in your Python code?

been writing too much typescript lately. my bad! now fixed

What you're asking for (if I understand the question, which is a very big if) has some very clean syntax available in Python 3.12, thanks to PEP-695, but was available in a less usable form well before. I suspect that a less pretty solution might be feasible with PEP-646 features only, but... again, this question is to my eyes pretty broad/unclear ("metaprogramming, dynamic types and static type checking" is three very broad features)

BTW, note that PEP-695 isn't supported in mypy -- if you aren't already using it, you'll want to switch to pyright. I also don't see any obvious reason for metaclasses to be involved here at all.
